# Weird behavior from pythons multiprocessing

Tags: python, multiprocessing

The code what I am trying is:

```
def update_vm(si, vm):
    env.host_string = vm
    with settings(user=VM_USER, key_filename=inputs['ssh_key_path']):
        put(local_file, remote_zip_file)
        run('tar -zxpf %s' % remote_zip_file)
        run('sudo sh %s' % REMOTE_UPDATE_SCRIPT)
        response_msg = run('cat %s' % REMOTE_RESPONSE_FILE)
        if 'success' in response_msg:
            #do stuff
        else:
            #do stuff

def update_vm_wrapper(args):
    return update_vm(*args)

def main():
    try:
        si = get_connection()
        vms = [vm1, vm2, vm3...]
        update_jobs = [(si, vm) for vm in vms]
        pool = Pool(30)
        pool.map(update_vm_wrapper, update_jobs)
        pool.close()
        pool.join()
    except Exception as e:
        print e
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Now the problem is I saw it is trying to put the zip file inside same vm(say vm1)for 3 times(I guess the length of `vms`). And trying to execute the other ssh commands 3 times.

Using locks for the update_vm() method is solving the issue. But it looks no longer a multiprocessor solution. It more like iterating over a loop.

What wrong am I doing here ?

Comment: Where do you get `env` from?

Comment: That is fabric library for ssh ops

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fabric has its own facilities for [parallel execution of tasks](http://fabric.readthedocs.org/en/1.8/usage/parallel.html) - you should use those, rather than just trying to execute Fabric tasks in multiprocessing pools. The problem is that the `env` object is mutated when executing the tasks, so the different workers are stepping on each other (unless you put locking in).

Comment: Excellent ! I didn't know that fabric has it's own support for parallel execution. And that also using a simple decorator @parallel